# Get years from articles

Tags: php, mysql, database, timeline

Table articles

```
id - content - ins_dt
1 - lorem ipsum1 - 2013-01-09
2 - lorem ipsum2 - 2013-02-08
3 - lorem ipsum3 - 2012-11-03
4 - lorem ipsum4 - 2011-01-20
5 - lorem ipsum5 - 2011-12-13
6 - lorem ipsum6 - 2010-05-12
```

With query

```
SELECT ins_dt FROM articles ORDER BY ins_dt DESC;
```

I get this: ([http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc9ea6/5](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc9ea6/4))

```
"2013 2013 2012 2011 2011 2010"
```

But I need this:

```
"2013 2012 2011 2010"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple SQL query

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT YEAR(ins_dt)) AS `year` 
FROM articles 
ORDER BY ins_dt DESC;
```

Here is the sample and demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc9ea6/3

Answer (score 2):

Whatever the values you are getting store them in array

then `$finaldata = array_unique($yourarray);`

Comment: While I also thought of this at first, it will only work if the year is the only element of his array. If he is pulling additional data, the elements in the array may still be unique even if they have the same year in them. +1 anyhow for beating me to the buzzer :)

Comment: Thanks buddy, I just answered to his actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

try sort http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

```
sort($myarr['ins_dt'], SORT_NUMERIC); 
 print_r($myarr);
```

a little searching effort could land you on great links like this one
http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Answer (score 0):

As you have the data in an array, you can easily use [Array unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) in your code, which will give you an array with only unique values in it.

Alternately, you could change your SQL to only pull the data you need from the table itself like this:

```
select distinct year from (select date_format(ins_dt, '%Y') from tableArticles) myData)
```